# Proving that $x^4+3y^4=777\ldots777$ (with $n$ digits) has no integer solution for any positive $n$, and similar questions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

I was looking at my Algebra book and there were some questions I couldn't really know how to solve. They are of similar type. Here they go:

$1.$ Prove that equation $x^{4}+3y^{4} = 777...777$ (number of the digits is $n$) has no integer solution for any positive integer $n$.

$2.$ Does the equation $x^{5}-x+y^{2} = 12345678$ have any integer solutions?

$3.$ Is there a positive integer $x$ such that $2^{x}+x^{2}=555555555$?

$4.$ Is there an integer $x$ such that $x^{2}+x=987654$?

$5.$ Is there an integer $x$ such that $x(x+1)(x+2)=98765432$?

Is there any same method for solving those problems, or is the method individual for each problem, and how to solve them? The only restriction is no modulo. Thank you in advance.

Comment: For question $5$, $98765432$ is not divisible by $3$.

Comment: Perhaps attack these one at a time, and provide your own insight for each.

Comment: "The only restriction is no modulo" ?????????

Comment: I think I know the first one. $x^{4}$ must end with $0, 2, 4, 6, 8$, and so must $y^{4}$, and as an even number times $3$ is also even, $7$, an odd number, can't be produced as a last digit. Is it right?

Comment: I can't take answers of form $x^{4}\equiv 0, 1$ $(mod$ $5)$.

Comment: @Vedast Questions 3, 4, and 5 are all about piecewise-monotonic functions of x only, no terms with y in them. This means that if you find consecutive integer inputs that "straddle" the desired output, then there are no solutions in the entire monotonic segment. For example,  if you seek integer solutions to $$x^2 + x = 32$$ then it is sufficient to note two things: (1) that $x=5$ is too low and $x=6$ is too high, and (2) that $x=-6$ gives too low an output and $x=-7$ gives too large an output. The function monotonically increases when $x>0$, and monotonically in decreases when $x<0$.

Comment: This method will work for all three questions, but there are faster (and imo, better) methods for all of them. For example, for the fifth question as @AndrewChin already suggested: Note that a product of three consecutive integers must contain a factor of $3$, while the right-hand-side does not, so there are no solutions.

Comment: Thank you, it helps.